# i am trying to sign in elasticsearch but i am getting this error

Tags: elasticsearch

this is command to set user: elasticsearch-users useradd suchit -p suchit -r network,monitoring
but after running elasticsearch.bat  on cmd  i am getting error as follows:

```json
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "security_exception",
        "reason": "action [cluster:monitor/main] is unauthorized for user [suchit] with roles [monitoring,network], this action is granted by the cluster privileges [monitor,manage,all]"
      }
    ],
    "type": "security_exception",
    "reason": "action [cluster:monitor/main] is unauthorized for user [suchit] with roles [monitoring,network], this action is granted by the cluster privileges [monitor,manage,all]"
  },
  "status": 403
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Tldr;

Reading the error message goes a long way.

You need to add at least the role `monitor` to your user `suchit`.

## Solution

Based of the exemple in [the documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/users-command.html):

```
bin/elasticsearch-users roles suchit -a monitor
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check if key is correct or not in user_roles

e.g **admins** insted of **admin**

```
admins:
monitor:
monitoring:
network:
```